# iOS - MKAnnotationView Custom UIButton issue

Tags: ios, uibutton, mkmapview, mkannotationview

After adding a custom `UIButton` to `MKAnnotationView`, the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` for the button is not working.

Please have a look at my code below :

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier"];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
       annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location-pin"];

        UIButton *rightButton   =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        rightButton.frame       =   CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 30);
        [rightButton setTitle:annotationText.userName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rightButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        rightButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        rightButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted   =   YES;
        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rightAcccoryViewButtonCLicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    }
    else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return annotationView;
}
return nil;

}
```

The `rightButton` is getting initialised properly with value. But when I hit the button at **centre**, its not getting recognised. 
[image]

However, when the button is tapped at the **`rightside`** control moves to

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

.

Is it not possible to get the action when tapped at the `centre` other than adding to  **`rightCalloutAccessoryView`** ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[self.mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"Pin"];
    if(pinView == nil)
    {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"] ;
    }

 UIButton *detailButton = [[UIButton  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 100)];
        [detailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addToListButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [detailButton setSelected:NO];
        pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = detailButton;
        [pinView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"locationPin.png"]];
        [pinView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 55)];
        pinView.animatesDrop = NO;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
       // [pinView setSelected:YES animated:YES];


    return pinView;

}

-(void)addToListButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    int temp =2;
   AnnotationViewController *ann1 =[sender superview];
    NSString *str = ann1.title;
    NSLog(@"button tapped");
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    }
```

Comment: Still the Button is getting initialised with rightCalloutAccessoryView. Nothing happens when I tap at the centre.

Comment: use my edited answer and change button frame as u want, it works fine.

Comment: thanks for that ! but how do I get the annotation values from addToListButtonTapped?

Comment: thanks man. One last question -  the title of my button is being shown two times. Why is it so? Eg: the original button title should be : "what is your name ...", but what I'm getting is "what is your name.. what".

Comment: increase ur button width or do not set ur button title

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43983/discussion-between-sree127-and-aklesh-rathaur)

Answer (score 0):

(i). First try using a rounded rectangle button, then use the custom button.
(ii). then, check the image name is same as the name in the resource folder